# How to disable parent window while the child pop-up window is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a parent screen, containing a button, on click of which 
**window.open("URL", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");**
is invoked, which in turn returns to child screen.

The child screen also contains some buttons which perform CRUD operations, using request-response mechanism, due to which the URL of the parent window needs to be updated, and hence, reloading of parent screen is required.

I want to disable the parent screen irrespective whether the parent screen gets reloaded.

I found jQuery block UI relevant for this option but found following 2 issues:

1. Using jQuery block UI disabled the parent screen only until it get reloaded. After reloading, it again became enabled while my child pop-up was still open.
2. jQuery block UI supports IE version 9 & above, but my requirement is to make IE version 5 compatible.

Please suggest correct solution for this scenario.

Comment: IE 5!? I really hope wherever this spec is coming from it's realized IE5 is getting pretty close to 20 years old (18 and counting quickly). A lot of Javascript, HTML, CSS that modern webpages make seem trivial weren't even beginning to be a thing yet. Additionally, I'd say a new window and UI blocking a bad practice almost always.

Comment: For IE5, you can use window.showModalDialog instead of window.open, but this function is not support in Chrome or Firefox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think there is a way to prevent user from reloading the page. Instead, you can use an iframe in a [BlockUI modal dialog](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog) so that when the user reload the parent page, the popup (as an iframe inside the parent page) will also be closed.
2. For IE5, you can use [`Window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog), but it won't support in Chrome and Firefox, so you may want to [check the which browser the user is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) before calling the popup function.